# javascript - Detecting a specific browser on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, browser-detection

Im looking for a way to detect if the user is using **Opera Mini on iPad**. The reason why I want to do that is because Opera Mini on iPad does not support HTML5's "video" tag or Flash. I need to be able to have a static image loading in my video container in that specific case.

Is there any way of detecting this??

Im already using the ipad detection like:

```
 var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
 if (isiPad){ ... }
```

Now, can I get that specific browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for `<video>` support directly using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5).

Comment: Modernizr looks good but if you only want to check for opera mini in the user-agent then check for the term opera in the UA.. the list of opera mini UA is [here] (http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-request-headers/).

Comment: @PunitRaizada Checking for user agents has been considered bad practice for roughly forever. While there may be circumstances when it's the least bad of bad solutions, this isn't one. Checking for `<video>` support will likely make the code clearer and useful on any other browser that needs the fallback.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will answer your question. 
https://www.handsetdetection.com/features/mobile-browser-detection

I hope this helps.